# What do you put for a Object Array Identifier when creating an element of the object?

Tags: java, arrays, object, identifier

Imagine an array of objects.

```
int MAX_ALLOWED = 5;
Object [] object = new Object [MAX_ALLOWED];
```

*Suppose the object was a unit for a game with its respective location.* When the user presses a button called *"spawn unit"* the code will be:

```
 unit [] = new Object (location);
```

As you can see there is no identifier in the **[ _ ]** so this presents the problem. I don't know what to put in here.If I put 0 it will over-ride the memory of the object at 0 every-time I create an object.

When accessing a particular object or unit.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= unit.length; i++)
    {
    if (location = unit [i].get_Location)
    {
        move (unit [i]);
        }
    }
```

But doing this will give me a null-pointer exception if I access an element after 0.

Comment: Consider using a `List` implementation, such as `ArrayList`.

Comment: Also make sure to do `for (int i = 0; i < unit.length; i++)` or there's an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in your future.

Comment: What's the logic you are trying to implement? When are you initializing the objects stored in the `unit` array? What is `move` supposed to do? In addition, you probably meant `==` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays should be avoided for the general problem of storing lists of things. Instead, Collections are far more programmer friendly, and still pretty fast.

In your case, using an array would mean having to keep the index of the last used element and manage the size, etc, etc. Using a `List` is way easier:

```
List<Unit> units = new ArrayList<Unit>();
```

then to use, simply:

```
units.add(new Unit());
```

if you want to restrict the size, before you add:

```
if (units.size() == MAX_ALLOWED) {
    // do something else
}
```

To iterate over the elements:

```
for (Unit unit : units) {
    // do something with unit
}
```

A good thing about Lists is they will grow in size as needed, although in your case this may not be needed as you seem to want a fixed maximum.

Comment: How would I store the attributes for the object in the list (x location and y location)?

Comment: My initial response would be to store the objects in a list, and have the objects have their own attributes of x and y. Would that work? Or do you need to be able to find objects based on their x or y values? Tell me what you're really trying to accomplish here - maybe there's a standard approach that can help you.

Comment: Imagine I am making a game that has a grid. Within this grid there are units at (x,y) coords, respectively. I want a way to access these units. Now if I use multiple units (objects) I need a 'Object Array',right? My confusion stems on how to reference these units.